# Send only specific headers in specific order to replicate a real request

Tags: python, http, python-requests, reverse-engineering

I need to call a API, but the request needs to look like a real request made by the app

- Only specific headers
- In specific order (can't verify it)

For sending only specific headers I tried:

- Setting a `None` parameter to a header, it sent the header anyway
- Using `urllib3.util.SKIP_HEADER`, but it only workd for `Accept-Encoding`, `Host` and `User-Agent`, I need to remove other headers too

For sending headers in specific order I tried:

- Just using a dict to store headers
- Using a OrderedDict
  But `requests` just sends them in random order

Sending the request as is throws an 403 error. Any way to fix it?